# Why does having a high input impedance and low output impedance cause minimal voltage drop when you connect two circuits?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

Say you connect Circuit A with low output impedance to circuit B with high input impedance. Why does this cause minimal voltage drop compared to connecting them the other way around (high output to low input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this cause minimal voltage drop compared to connecting them
> the other way around?

The two word answer is - voltage division.

The output impedance of circuit A is in series with the input impedance of circuit B and, thus, the two impedances form a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

As you may know, the voltage across the output and input impedances are in proportion to the ratio of the respective impedance to the sum, i.e.

$$V_{Z_{out}} = V_A\frac{Z_{out}}{Z_{in} + Z_{out}}$$

$$V_{Z_{in}} = V_A\frac{Z_{in}}{Z_{in} + Z_{out}}$$

where $Z_{out}$ is the output impedance of circuit A, $Z_{in}$ is the input impedance of circuit B, and $V_A$ is the output voltage of circuit A when there is no circuit B connected (the *open-circuit* voltage for circuit A).

It simply follows that, for the most voltage to be across the input impedance of circuit B (the least voltage to be across the output impedance of circuit A), we want

$$V_{Z_{in}} \gg V_{Z_{out}} \Leftrightarrow Z_{in} \gg Z_{out}$$

In the ideal limit, we have $Z_{out} \rightarrow 0$ and $Z_{in} \rightarrow \infty$ so that *all* the open-circuit voltage of circuit A is across the input of circuit B, i.e., there is maximal voltage transfer from A to B.

Comment: So, if the two impedances are in series, current will be constant correct? So will creating a higher voltage across the input impedance of B create more power for circuit B?

Comment: The thing I'm the most confused about is why this causes minimal voltage drop. Would there not be a reflected wave if the two impedances are different? Is the best option not to match the impedances so there is no reflected wave?

Comment: @alexanderd5398, if the context is radio frequency (RF) design and s-parameters, then concern about (conjugate) matching of the impedances is appropriate for maximum *power* transfer.  But this doesn't seem to be the context so why the concern for reflected waves?  For maximum *voltage* transfer, you want as little voltage drop across the output impedance as possible which means making $Z_{in}/Z_{out}$ large (enough).

Comment: The concern for reflected waves is because that's what I am currently learning in this class. This is for a lab report, but I guess they are expecting us to learn this on our own, since we were never taught it. This isn't even a circuits course :/

Comment: Anyway,I think I understand now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So this is a very important lesson about real voltage sources: in general they are not ideal. If you start trying to pull current off of them you will find that they cannot sustain the exact voltage that your multimeter measures. Instead generally the voltage slackens  to some $V_1 = V_0 - I~r$ for some "impedance" $R.$ (This is also called an internal resistance; the distinction is that one can talk about impedance as a complex value in order to include the phase shifts of AC circuits, which allows us to compactly describe inductors and capacitors in the same language as resistors, and ultimately signal filters can be described nicely in general.)

Now your circuit is effectively going to connect to ground with some resistance (respectfully, impedance) $R$ and this is going to dictate the current, $I = V_1 / R.$ This means that the total expression we had before is $$V_1 = V_0 - \frac{V_1}{R}~r,$$ and we can solve for $V_1$ then as $$V_1 = \frac{V_0}{1 - r/R}.$$The conditions under which we don't need to care about this effect are precisely those conditions where $V_1 \approx V_0$ which demands that $1 - r/R \approx 1,$ hence $r/R \approx 0.$ So we need $r$ to be small compared to $R$ for us to not care about this effect, otherwise we have what we describe as an "impedance mismatch" where the "real" voltage that we're getting from our voltage source is not what we think we're getting.

Comment: Could you try to explain in a more physical way, i.e. what happens to voltage/current wave when it goes from a low impedance to a high impedance?

Comment: @alexanderd5398 slap a $(t)$ (or $[\omega]$ in Fourier-space) onto everything I just said and you have the equivalent for AC. So when you start to draw current off of a signal source $V_0[\omega]$ the voltage slackens to some $V_1[\omega] = V_0[\omega] + I[\omega]~z$ for some impedance $z$, then your circuit is going to connect to ground with some impedance $Z$  and this will in turn dictate the current $I[\omega] = V_1[\omega]/Z,$ so then we find that $V_1[\omega] = V_0[\omega]/(1 - z/Z)$ and therefore $|V_1[\omega]| \approx |V_0[\omega]|$ requires $|1-z/Z|\approx 1,$ etc.

Comment: Note that there is no "what happens when it goes from a low impedance to a high impedance", both are part of setting what the actual signal ends up being.

Comment: Can you try to explain it in a more basic way. We just have an output going to an input (no ground). Why does having a low output impedance and a high input impedance cause minimal voltage loss?

Comment: @alexanderd5398 if you do not connect your electrical components into a circuit you will see exactly zero voltage loss as no current will flow anywhere. If you do, then your voltage source has two terminals, and I arbitrarily designate the one of lower voltage as "ground".

Comment: Okay well... can you try to explain in a different way so that I can intuitively understand it.  Like as a wave travelling through a rope?